# how to put background image path from remote web site?

Tags: html, css

I need grab images from Imgur to My web page background image

```
 <div style="background-image:url(); width:100%; height:100%;" class="zoom" >
```

My image path is https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SPP3.jpg

then how can I put this image to my background image url?

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the right image path: https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Kq8.jpg

Go to https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SPP3.jpg -> right click on image -> Copy image address

After this you need to put it into `background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Kq8.jpg');`

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) you can find some documentation for **background-image** using.

Remember to set an height for your div, because in your solution will be 100% of nothing so this can be a solution:

```html
 <div style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Kq8.jpg'); width:100%; height:200px; background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;" class="zoom" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Update image url  like this

```
<div style="background-image:url('https://i.imgur.com/QdMWFHZ.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:100%; height:100%;" class="zoom" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your image path, after that right click on the image and click "Copy image address".
And then paste address on your code.

```
<div style="background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/QdMWFHZ.jpg); width:100%; height:100%;" class="zoom" >
```

Comment: Please correct your answer:-> background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/QdMWFHZ.jpg")

Answer (score 0):

or in your CSS directly as `background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/QdMWFHZ.jpg")`

---

since you need background of webpage it would be part of the body attribute like (CSS):

```css
body  {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/QdMWFHZ.jpg")
}
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xr8ryy8d/)