# How can I put a url for my html background image?

Tags: css

Imagine that the following codes were written in an external css file: I want to know how to put a reference for my image.

```
body {background-image:url(?????)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to put background image path from remote web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281934/how-to-put-background-image-path-from-remote-web-site)

Comment: Did you try searching the site for the answer?

Comment: Please read this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp It will also assist with styling / sizing / repeating the background image.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this as an answer because I don't have the privilege to comment.

```
body {
background-image: url("<The link to be inserted here>");
background-color: #cccccc;
}
```